# Scala custom collection returns list of null as default values

Tags: scala, generics, default-value, scala-collections

I have made a custom collection called `Matrix` that stores a matrix in the form of a uni-dimensional `List` (this is sort of a requirement, has to be that way). The thing is, I want to implement this collection adapted for generics. But when I execute it and print the returned collection, it gives `null` values.

I have created an external class to help with the custom default values for each type.

Now, the snippets:

**Output**:

```sh
> sbt run
[info] welcome to sbt 1.4.9 (N/A Java 15.0.2)
[info] loading project definition from /home/pace/Documents/git/1024-scala/1024-scala/project
[info] loading settings for project root from build.sbt ...
[info] set current project to scalatest-example (in build file:/home/pace/Documents/git/1024-scala/1024-scala/)
[info] compiling 1 Scala source to /home/pace/Documents/git/1024-scala/1024-scala/target/scala-2.13/classes ...
[info] done compiling
[info] running matrix.MainClass 
Matrix(null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null)
[success] Total time: 4 s, completed May 1, 2021, 9:10:28 PM
```

The **Matrix collection** implementation:

```scala
package matrix

import scala.collection.Iterable
import scala.collection.Iterator
import scala.collection.AbstractIterator

import defaultValues.Default

class Matrix[A] private (val col: Int, val row: Int, elems: List[A])
    extends Iterable[A] { self =>

  def this() = this(col = 4, row = 4, elems = List.fill(4 * 4)(Default.value[A]))

  def this(s: Int) = this(col = s, row = s, elems = List.fill(s * s)(Default.value[A]))

  def this(c: Int, r: Int) = this(col = c, row = r, elems = List.fill(c * r)(Default.value[A]))

  def apply(i: Int): A = elems(i).asInstanceOf[A]

  def iterator: Iterator[A] = new AbstractIterator[A] {
    private var current = 0
    def hasNext = current < elems.size
    def next(): A = {
      val elem = self(current)
      current += 1
      elem
    }
  }

  override def className = "Matrix"
}

object MainClass extends App {
  val m = new Matrix[Int]()
  println(m)
}
```

And the way I obtain the **default values** for each type (got it from other SO thread, and I've checked it works in `Scala REPL`):

```scala
package defaultValues

import scala.collection.immutable

class Default[+A](val default: A)

trait LowerPriorityImplicits {
  // Stop AnyRefs from clashing with AnyVals
  implicit def defaultNull[A <: AnyRef]: Default[A] = new Default[A](null.asInstanceOf[A])
}

object Default extends LowerPriorityImplicits {
  implicit object DefaultString extends Default[String]("")
  implicit object DefaultDouble extends Default[Double](0.0)
  implicit object DefaultFloat extends Default[Float](0.0F)
  implicit object DefaultInt extends Default[Int](0)
  implicit object DefaultLong extends Default[Long](0L)
  implicit object DefaultShort extends Default[Short](0)
  implicit object DefaultByte extends Default[Byte](0)
  implicit object DefaultBoolean extends Default[Boolean](false)
  implicit object DefaultUnit extends Default[Unit](())

  implicit def defaultSeq[A]: Default[immutable.Seq[A]] = new Default[immutable.Seq[A]](immutable.Seq())
  implicit def defaultSet[A]: Default[Set[A]] = new Default[Set[A]](Set())
  implicit def defaultMap[A, B]: Default[Map[A, B]] = new Default[Map[A, B]](Map[A, B]())
  implicit def defaultOption[A]: Default[Option[A]] = new Default[Option[A]](None)

  def value[A](implicit value: Default[A]): A = value.default
}
```

I'm running `Scala 2.13`.

Could you give me a hand? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```scala
  def this() = this(col = 4, row = 4, elems = List.fill(4 * 4)(Default.value[A]))
```

because there is no constraint on `A`, you're telling the compiler that this function should work for *every* `A` possible, which means `A` here must be the maximal type in scala - `AnyRef`. Now that A is solved to be `AnyRef`, `Default.value[A]` always resolves to `defaultNull` regardless of what you put at the call site. And that makes sense, because you're saying that it should work with every type possible.

The solution is simply putting a constraint in A so that compiler doesn't infer that to be maximal type:

```scala
class Matrix[A: Default] {
  def this() = this(col = 4, row = 4, elems = List.fill(4 * 4)(Default.value[A]))
}

// equivalent to this form
def apply[A: Default]: Matrix[A] = new Matrix(col = 4, row = 4, elems = List.fill(4 * 4)(Default.value[A]))

// which is syntactic sugar for
def apply[A](implicit default: Default[A]): Matrix[A] = new Matrix(col = 4, row = 4, elems = ???
```

by putting the constraint there, you defer solving for `A` to the actual usage (calling `new Matrix[Int]`) because now compiler needs to know the actual `A` you have so that it can search for implicit parameter.

Comment: As a beginner to Scala. Mind you telling me how it works internally? It _links_ A to the `implicit object`s in `Default`? Or what does it do exactly? I don't mind if it's a more mathematical explanation as long as it is understandable.

Comment: `[A: Default]` is syntactic sugar for `[A](implicit default: Default[A])` . In english, it means: calling this function requires some type `A`, and an implicit parameter of type `Default[A]`, bound to the name `default`.

This is how the typeclass pattern encoded in Scala. There are several mechanics in place here: implicit parameter, usage of generic type parameter,... I'd recommend you take a look at https://books.underscore.io/scala-with-cats/scala-with-cats.html and go through chapter 1 to understand typeclass. Then feel free to hop in gitter channel scala/scala for any further questions